# How do I append list from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append list of data from success handler to a table rows, e.g.

```
function Table(data) {
    var rows = '';
    rows += '<tr......>'
}

function functionTwo() {
    $.ajax({
        ..........
    success: function (data) {
        $('#tabletr:last').after(rows);
    }
});
```

I wrote two simple functions, in `Table()` function I am building a table which gets populated via rows += ''. If `functionTwo()` is successful then the data gain from the result should be appended after rows += '' in Table function.

How would I do that?

Comment: what is the format of data?

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: functiontwo does not have access to rows as its not declared globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either declare rows globally outside the Table function or return rows like this and fix the selector `"#table tr:last"`

```
function Table(data) {
var rows = '';
rows += '<tr......>'
return rows;
}

 function functionTwo() {
$.ajax({
..........
success: function (data) {
$('#table tr:last').after(Table(data)); //Call table here
}
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I would like to append my result after rows, shouldn't be  `$('#table tr:last').after(Table(rows));` or $('#table tr:last').after(Table.rows);

Comment: Don't you want to create rows with `data` and then append it after the last row in `#table` ?

Answer (score 0):

you missed space  #table tr:last

```
var rows = '';
     function Table(data) {
    rows = '';
    rows += '<tr......>'
}

function functionTwo() {
    $.ajax({
        ..........
    success: function (data) {
        $('#table tr:last').after(rows);
    }
});
```

Comment: That can be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: If i  run this it will say rows not recognised because I haven't declared any where?

Comment: @User911 rows declare as global then only it s visible outside scope

Answer (score 0):

Remember this is ajax that runs asynchronously so you don't have the traditional step-by-step execution. However, taking advantage of the `$.Deferred` API and scope, you can overcome this:

```
var rows = '';

// Build your rows
rows += '<tr>...</tr>';

// call ajax method and await successful response
$.ajax({ ... })
  .done(function(data){
    // this is where you compile both tr and data together
  })
  .fail(function(){
    // here all you have is rows since the AJAX call failed
  })
  .always(function(){
    // If you wanted output no matter what, that's what the .always callback is for.
    // It executes after the done/fail callback. So you could populate rows with either
    // the data (done) or a fallback message (fail) then actually output it here.
  });
```

*Note: I'm not sure if you intend to call `Table(data)` using the AJAX result, but if you are that would be placed within the `.done()` callback (instead of populating the `rows` value head of the AJAX call).*